# file unmanaged save upload

Tags: 7, files, forms

I'm moving some existing functionality into a new Drupal site.

1. Files are uploaded via posted form
2. Their file names are prefixes with UID
3. They are then moved to temp holding directory
4. A cron job on another server SCPs the files in batches
5. The files are verified copied, then deleted via batch ssh command

**I'm looking for a clean way to handle (save) an uploaded file coming from a submitted form with an element of type 'file' without "managing" it.** I've browsed over `file_save_upload()` and like the validation/error handling it offers.

However, I'd rather not have the files exist in the managed file tables. I would need to modify my pulling server's cron job to trigger a managed deletes via web request.

Just as there is a `file_save_data()` and analogous `file_unmanaged_save_data()` I'm looking for `file_unmanaged_save_upload()`. I basically want the first half of `file_save_upload()` before it touch the database. It seems like something similar or a workaround should already exist but I haven't found one. I trying to avoid reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Not sure about the #4 and #5, but if you still need Drupal to handle the uploaded files (from new SCP'd location), you will need to use `file_save_upload`. Once the files are copied, update the file location to the new one (or go one step ahead and add a new stream wrapper).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I suggest using `file_save_upload()` anyway**, beacause ([as the API docs say](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!file.inc/function/file_save_upload/7)):

> The file will be added to the {file_managed} table as a temporary file. Temporary files are periodically cleaned. To make the file a permanent file, assign the status and use file_save() to save the changes.

So you don't need to worry about having the file "managed" by Drupal as long as you don't change the status of the file to `FILE_STATUS_PERMANENT`.

**Otherwise, if you really don't want this default behaviour** (and also no hooks to get invoked), just copy the file in your `form_submit()` using [`file_unmanaged_copy()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!file.inc/function/file_unmanaged_copy/7) (give it uploaded tmp file as source).

Answer (score 1):

You may create your own file_unmanaged_save_upload() which won't insert item into Drupal DB file_managed table.

I did. I copied file_save_upload() as file_unmanaged_save_upload() in /Drupal_root/includes/file.inc, and deleted "file_save()" in it, modify the last lines as below:

```
function file_unmanaged_save_upload(){
.....
if ($file = file_save($file)) {
    // Add file to the cache.
    $upload_cache[$source] = $file;
    return $file;
  }
  return FALSE;
}
```

It works as expected.